# css files are loading properly in django but no styling is visible on webpage

Tags: django

I have checked all the settings for django.
CSS is loaded properly but no styling is visible on web page.
I stopped the server and made changes and start it again, but it didn't work.

The code:

```
<head>
    <title>
        fire
    </title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/index2.css' %}"/>
</head>
```

Comment: What if you add `rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"` in the `<link>` tag?

Comment: still not working

Comment: It is better to post code in text form than as an image. It is better to read, and it can be copy-and-pasted.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load static %}
```

Note: better use `load static` instead of `load staticfiles`

Must be on the top of the html template

## First must configure your static url

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in settting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```